# Request is not send with subscribe

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to run this code:

```
Mono<String> personMono = Mono.just("wfw");

        WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://webhook.site");

        Mono<Void> result = client.post()
                .uri("/a6ad3a35-61c6-4bfc-8d8c-7e5a3e2462aa")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(personMono, String.class)
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(Void.class));

        result.subscribe();
```

But request is not send. Do you know what I need to add in order to make POST request? I can't find what I'm missing?